# Sum of column values via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add single column values via javascript

when user enter quantity than the quantity multiply with the price column and shown into the 'your bill' column. The problem is that when user click on order button than all the values from 'your bill' column will add and show on the screen.

kindly tell me how can i sum all values from 'your bill column'

[image]

My view file is

```
    <tbody>

<?php $i=0; foreach($result as $row){
?>
     <tr>
         <th class="item-lists">
             <?php echo $row->recipe_name;?>
         </th>
         <th class="pre-top">
            <?php echo $row->quantity;?>
         </th>
        <th class="pr-right">
            <span id="priceT<?php echo $i;?>" ><?php echo $row->price;?></span>
        </th>
        <th class="pr-right">

            <input type="text" class="container" value="" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur=";}" style="width: 60px" id="quantityT<?php echo $i;?>" onkeyup="CalculatePrice (<?php echo $i;?>)">
        </th>

         <th class="clearfix">
             <input type="text" class="container" value="" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}" style="width: 60px"id="TPrice<?php echo $i;?>">
         </th>
     </tr>
<?php
$i++;
} ?>
     </tbody>
```

and javascript code

```
 function CalculatePrice (id) {


        var startP = parseInt (document.getElementById ("priceT"+id).innerHTML);
        var startQ = parseInt (document.getElementById ("quantityT"+id).value);

        var Bill = 0;
        if (!isNaN ( startP)&&!isNaN(startQ))
        {var Bill = startP * startQ}


        document.getElementById ("TPrice"+id).value =  Bill;



    }
```

Comment: this can be done easily using knockoutjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could works :

First set a new class to the `<th class="clearfix">` like... `<th class="clearfix product-price">` and add a `data-price` to your inputs with the price (for security reasons, an user can change the value of an input text).

Then with javascript :

```
var order = document.getElementById('order');
var totalPrice = 0;

order.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var productsPrice = document.getElementsByClassName('product-price');
    console.log(productsPrice);
    for(var i = 0; i < productsPrice.length; i++){
        totalPrice += parseInt(productsPrice[i].dataset.price);
    }
    alert("Total = "+totalPrice);
});
```

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/foguhoz8/).

Personally I used `span` instead of text `input` for the reason I explained before.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the input fields of the "Your bill" column:

```
<input type="text" class="container row-total" value="" />
```

Assuming your "Order" button has id "order-btn":

```
<button id="order-btn">Order</button>
```

Use a listener and calculate the total:

```
document.getElementById('order-btn').addEventListener('click',function(){
    var rowTotals = document.getElementsByClassName('row-total');
    var orderTotal = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < rowTotals.length; i++){
        orderTotal += parseFloat(rowTotals[i].value);
    }
    alert(orderTotal);
});
```

A jQuery alternative:

```
$(function(){
    $('#order-btn').click(function(){
        var orderTotal = 0;
        $('.row-total').each(function(){
                orderTotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
        alert(orderTotal);
    });
});
```

Comment: Since OP uses jQuery, an alternative could be added (it is probably better not to mix both for cohesion reasons)

Comment: @aduch I don't see jQuery in the code shown in the question

Comment: It is mentionned In the related tags, though

Comment: @aduch jQuery version added